# copying fils to external storage error

Tags: usb, external-hdd

Every time i want to copy a file or a folder to an external storage the files size gets a lot less when i see it from the other PC (Ubuntu is not copying all the file)

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and every time i copy stuff to my USB when i want to see them on my win 8 laptop the files seems missing if it was a single file it size is much smaller 
even thought it is taking a long time to copy it from the Ubuntu to the USB flash stick
and i wait till Ubuntu copy bar completely finish copying (i don't interrupt it)

i tried to copy files to 3 USB sticks ans 1 external HDD
all the same (missing data)

I'm so confused it i haven't ever had problems when i used win 7 before i installed Ubuntu.

Note : I'm using graphical copy i had never user terminal copy
*any ideas ?
*the problem still even when i run Ubuntu without installing it

Comment: try terminal copy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you unmount the USB stick safely? In the file manager there is an "eject" icon near the drive name. You can also try to run the `sync` command (no arguments, just "sync") in a terminal.